# Open with... from the terminal. windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe

Is there a way to open the Open with.. dialog (see screenshots) from a cmd/shell in windows 10?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the command prompt's syntax is always to run the program first i.e. program.exe with various parameters i.e. program.exe /d /s

So in theory, you can run the program you want to use with the file you want to open as a parameter for example to open file with MS Word, you would do:

```
winword.exe <filepath>
```

i.e.

```
winword.exe c:\documents\file.docx
```

Answer (score 1):

The command prompt has this awesome command called `start`

Start can be used to start the associated program to a file format.

If you have Word installed and you want to open a Word document called `myfile.docx` you can simply type: `start myfile.docx` and it will launch Word.

If you give a path rather than a filename, Explorer is opened with that path.

For example:

```
c:\>cd c:\temp

c:\temp>start .
```

An explorer will be started that begins in c:\temp.

It is not possible to actually show the "open with" dialog itself, but if you type start . to open an explorer in the current folder, you can then rightclick the file and perform the open with action manually or through keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

You can open this dialog with the following command (Rundll32 allows you to run a function in a dynamic library directly from cmd/powershell):

```
Rundll32 Shell32.dll,OpenAs_RunDLL path\to\you\file.extension
```

Note that this **only works with absolute paths**.

Comment: This is precisely what I needed! Thank you!